# How to override css for overrided template

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, css, theme-overriding

I override the **module_catalog** from template and put it in following directory

**`app/design/frontend/gog/gogparent/Magento_Catalog/template`**

(gogparent is my custom theme)that inherit to blank theme. It works fine,
the question is how can I **override css** for **Module_catalog** from **blank theme** to my **gog theme** and have some changes..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. You can copy the original LESS file from `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_module.less` to your custom theme. This can be used when you want to override a lot of stuff in that file.
2. You can create a new file called `app/design/frontend/gog/gogparent/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_extend.less`. In this file you can add all your custom styling, which comes on top of the default styling of `Magento_Catalog` that's in the Blank theme.

Personally I'm more a fan of option 2, since that reduces the number of work you have when upgrading Magento, because if the styling of a module changes in the Blank theme, you don't have to copy the entire file. And I like to add an addition to option 2 as well. What I normally do is this:

**_extend.less**

```
@import 'extend/_grid';
@import 'extend/_productview';
```

Now I put all my customisations into these separate files, which gives me a much better overview of the changes per pagetype. You only need to create a folder `app/design/frontend/gog/gogparent/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/extend` and put all these separate less files in there.

Comment: Thanks for helping.how I know home page read which of style?a original style or overrided style?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Can you specify it a bit more so I can answer your question.

Comment: I cant find path of css for changing them,how I can find css path of specific part of page?

Comment: The extend files don't exist in the Blank theme (at least not for Magento_Catalog, I'm not 100% sure if that goes for all cases). You need to create a new file for that in your own theme: `app/design/frontend/gog/gogparent/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_extend.less`. Magento will automatically detect that file and use if for generating your stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override **.less** files from `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source` in your custom theme. Then flush cache and run deploy command.

For example you can copy **_module.less** file from that folder to your custom theme folder `app/design/frontend/gog/gogparent/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/` and then you can do required customization in it.